# When a certain word is repeated in lines, print something in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

1. Whenever the word "Run" comes in line, then print "Vader".
2. If the word "Alert" repeats consecutively before "Run", then print "skip" equal to the number of times it repeats.

**Sample input**

*Alert and be on guard*

*Run for your life*

*Alert and be on guard*

*Alert and be on guard*

*Run for your life*

*Alert and be on guard*

*Alert and be on guard*

*Alert and be on guard*

*Run for your life*

*Alert and be on guard*

*Alert and be on guard*

*Run for your life*

**My code so far**

```
sys.stdout = open("filepath/output.csv", "w")
with open("filepath/input.txt", "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                if "Run" in line:
                    print("Vader")

sys.stdout.close()
```

**current output**

Vader

Vader

Vader

Vader

**Required output**

Vader

skip

Vader

skip

skip

Vader

skip

Vader

As you can see, I have completed the first requirement. Can't figure out the second part. Can someone help with point#2? Or point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the lines, and whenever there is "Alert", increment a counter. If the counter is > 1, print "skip". When Alert is not present, reset counter to 0.

```py
counter = 0
for line in f:
    if "Run" in line:
        print("Vader")
        counter = 0
    elif "Alert" in line:
        if counter > 1:
            prit("skip")
        counter += 1
```